# [__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 8 beyond bounds [0 .. 7]'

Tags: iphone, ios6

I'm new to iOS development and as I follow a tutorial my app continues to crash but I cant see why..

```
2012-11-07 11:52:30.657 SliderList[2725:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 8 beyond bounds [0 .. 7]'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1c8d012 0x10cae7e 0x1c42b44 0x2cb2 0x10de705 0x15920 0x158b8 0xd6671 0xd6bcf 0x15c52d 0xd5968 0x451bd 0x45552 0x233aa 0x14cf8 0x1be8df9 0x1be8ad0 0x1c02bf5 0x1c02962 0x1c33bb6 0x1c32f44 0x1c32e1b 0x1be77e3 0x1be7668 0x1265c 0x26bd 0x25e5 0x1)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

---

```
 #import "ViewController.h"
   NSArray *keuzeArray;

   @interface ViewController ()

   @end

   @implementation ViewController
   @synthesize keuze;
   - (IBAction)sliderValueChanged: (UISlider *)sender
   {
self.keuze.text = [keuzeArray objectAtIndex:sender.value];
   }

   - (void)viewDidLoad
   {
[super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

keuzeArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
              @"Koffie zwart", @"Koffie melk", @"Koffie melk&suiker", @"cafe au lait",               @"Koud water", @"Heet water", @"Chocomel", @"Wiener melange", nil];
   }
   - (void) viewDidUnload
   {
[super viewDidUnload];
   }

   - (BOOL) shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:
   (UIInterfaceOrientation)InterfaceOrientation
   {
return (InterfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
   }

   @end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling a object from your array that the index is not on your array.

Basically your array has 8 elements (`0 to 7`) and you are calling the index `8`

Just change this line:

```
self.keuze.text = [keuzeArray objectAtIndex:(sender.value - 1)];
```

and it all should work

Answer (score 1):

Your slider's max value is outside the number of elements in your model array.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the `UISlider` in the `sliderValueChanged:` method is passed with the value of `8`. Since indexes in `NSArray` are zero-based, you cannot ask for an element beyond `7`.

You need to re-configure your slider, setting the minimum value at `0` and the maximum value at `7`.

Answer (score 0):

You have only `8` elements.
**In arrays, index starts from 0**. So the last element index in your array is `7`.
If you try to get the element at index `8` or above an exception (`NSRangeException`) will occur and your app will crash.
**So check the array bounds when you try to get an element from the arrays.**

Answer (score 0):

Your Array has 8 objects with index 0 to 7.
And you are trying to access the object at index 8. Thats why its throwing exceptional error.

Answer (score 0):

If it’s in UITableView:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return arrayResponse.count-1;
}
```